# Android: Count Down Timer e.g. 10:00 to 00:00? using OnclickListener to TextView?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a countdown timer starting at 10 minutes, similair to a basketball scoreboard: 10:00 to 00:00. How would I do that? This is my code:

```
private TextView Timer;  
Handler handler = new Handler();  
private int length = 120000;  
private int decision = 0;  
MyCount counter;  

public String formatTime(long millis) {  
    String output = "00:00";  
    long seconds = millis / 1000;  
    long minutes = seconds / 60;  

    seconds = seconds % 60;  
    minutes = minutes % 60;  

    String sec = String.valueOf(seconds);  
    String min = String.valueOf(minutes);  

    if (seconds < 10)  
        sec = "0" + seconds;  
    if (minutes < 10)  
        min= "0" + minutes;  

    output = min + " : " + sec;  
    return output;
}//formatTime  

@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle cute) {  
    super.onCreate(cute);  
    counter = new MyCount(length, 1000);  
    updateTime();  
    handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimeTask);  
    handler.postDelayed(updateTimeTask, 1000);   
}//end of cuteness  

private Runnable updateTimeTask = new Runnable() {  
    public void run() {  
        updateTime();  
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);  
    }  
};  

private void updateTime() {  
    switch (decision) {  
        case 0:  
            startTime = 0L;  
            counter.start();  
            decision=1;  
            break;  
        case 1:  
            counter.onPause();  
            decision=0;  
            break;  
    }  
}//updateTime  

class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {  
    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {  
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);  
    }//MyCount  

    public void onPause() {  
        //do stuff later  
        onPause();  
    }//finish  

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {             
        Timer.setText("" + formatTime(millisUntilFinished));           
    }//on tick  

    @Override  
    public void onFinish() {  
        onStop();  

    }//finish  
}//class MyCount
```

Any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: awesome code for formatTime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does not have to be too hard. You've already created your functionality for writing your time in letters, now you need to count down. Starting a timer is easy, just do this in your start button event handler (or whatever you choose to use) (modified example from the [android developer reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html):

```
// New timer for 10 minutes, starts after initialization
new MyCount(600000, 1000) 
{
    // Updates the text on your "scoreboard" every second
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
    {
        Timer.setText("Time remaining: " + formatTime(millisUntilFinished));
    }

    public void onFinish() 
    {
        mTextField.setText("done!");
    }
}.start();
```

And that's all you need! You can skip your `UpdateTime` function and your `updateTimeTask`. Just replace all this on your `onCreate` method

```
counter = new MyCount(length, 1000);  
updateTime();  
handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimeTask);  
handler.postDelayed(updateTimeTask, 1000);
```

With my code. Or modify it as you please!

Comment: You can call `cancel` on the `MyCount` object: `counter.cancel()`, as specified in the linked reference.

Comment: Yes, but I don't have counter object. You said to replace all that code, including counter with your code, and there is no counter in your code.

Comment: First row of second code block in my post above: `counter = new MyCount(length, 1000);` There's your counter object :)

Comment: Does this timer cancel it self on activity finish?

Comment: Also, now I have two onFinish() methods, one in your code and one in MyCount class. In which onFinish() should i place my code for the stuff that goes on after time ends?

Comment: Also, i the counter object is in onCreate() method scope, how can I use it's start and cancel functions outside the onCreate method?? Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: I'm sorry to say I really don't understand your comment about `onFinish`-methods. Perhaps you should read up on it on the linked documentation? And as for the scope, you could easily make your counter variable a member of the class you are starting your counter in.

Comment: Well, I don't understand this: you start your timer with new MyCount with 60s, and also you start one in onCreate method with counter = new MyCount with 120s. I get error when using counter.cancel(); nullPointExeption. I made the counter variable a member of the class.

Comment: Please read my post in full. I recommended that the original asker replace his code (my lower code block) with my code (upper code block). Just think for a second how you could assign anything my upper code block would return to a member variable. Helping you out step-by-step isn't really the purpose of SO: if you've got a bigger problem you should perhaps create a new question?

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood your post. I get it know. I was going in my mind trying to understand why did you use two different timers. :) Does your timer get canceled on activity finish()?

Comment: It's alright! I'm sorry, unfortunately I don't know the answer to your question. You could pretty easily test it for yourself with a small test app, using logs or something similar. Try it out, experiment! :)

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just create 3 textviews so that it will be easier for you to code?

one for the minutes. 
one for the colon.
one for the seconds.

then use the code he's using.

hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

The way i think of making a count down is just saving at the beginning the (current time + 10 minutes) aside and then just subtract it from current time every second in your handler and display the result in the desired format..

Comment: how would I do that? sorry i am noob in terms of android and java programming XD