# How to build a countdown timer?

Tags: java, android

I am new in android and java programming, and I want to make a CountDown Timer just like a scoreboard. Timer for mm:ss/ 10:00.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292697/android-count-down-timer-e-g-1000-to-0000-using-onclicklistener-to-textview.. The code I had done

Answer (score 4):

Here is `CountDownTimer` class for android :: [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Schedule a countdown until a time in the future, with regular notifications on intervals along the way. Example of showing a 30 second countdown in a text field:

```
new CountdownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```

Comment: hmm yea it is only count down for 30 seconds... what if it was like for mm:ss?  seperate countdown for mm and ss? should I use SingleDateFormat / "mm:ss"? I am also using that but cant figure out. Thanks for the help X)

Comment: useing date function you get time and date now put it in to timer and you can get countdown.

Answer (score 0):

Android has a built-in [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html), which you should be using.